# What's the difference between using shell command (e.g. foo) directly and using $(foo)?

Tags: bash, shell

I get confused about using command directly and using $(foo).
I'm using Mac, I try to list apps which is install by `brew cask`(a package manager), and echo each app.
I have two short Shell scripts, first one like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
apps=$(brew cask list)
for app in ${apps}
do
    echo  "${app}"
done
```

It works fine, however another likes this:

```
#!/bin/bash
apps=$(brew cask list)
myecho=$(echo)
for app in ${apps}
do
    ${myecho}  "${app}"
done
```

This one returns `./script2.sh: line 7: foo: command not found`,  `foo` is the name of app.
What's the difference between I use echo directly and using `myecho` as a aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this command

```
myecho=$(echo)
```

you are setting `myecho` to an empty token.  So the following command

```
${myecho}  "${app}"
```

is simply `"${app}"`, which is apparently "foo" (not what was intended).  You would make an *alias* using different syntax:

```
alias myecho="echo"
```

Further reading:

- [2.3.1 Alias Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) (POSIX)
- [2.6.3 Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) (POSIX, explaining `$(` use)

Comment: Is that means no matter which command, when I use `$(foo)`, I just got the result of executing the command rather than store it as alias?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting an alias. In `myecho=$(echo)`, `echo` is executed, and its output (nothing, as the echo has nothing to echo) is stored in the variable `myecho`. This, however, has some output from echo:

```
$ myecho=$(echo "Hello")
$ echo "$myecho"
Hello
```

And the variable `myecho` stored it.

---

What I believe you want in the second script is to execute `echo` by using the variable `myecho`. That is done like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
apps=$(brew cask list)
myecho="echo"
for app in ${apps}
do
    ${myecho}  "${app}"
done
```

---

All the above has nothing to do with an alias. An alias is defined by this:

```
alias myecho='echo'
```

But then, the line to execute the alias should not have an `$`:

```
myecho "${apps}"
```